# use toString and substring method in ejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to display an employee id as just the last four numbers in a table on a ejs page. I am using mongodb to store the data and express for the routes.

I have my express route as:

```
app.get('/routehere', async (req, res) => { 
const expressModelName = await expressModelName.find({})
res.render('employee.ejs', {expressModelName});
})
```

then my for loop in the ejs file:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < expressModelName.length; i++) {%>
<div> styling here</div>
<%= expressModelName[i].id %>
```

i am trying to display the last four of the id. ive tried:

```
id.toString.substring(5,8)
id.slice(5)
```

being that the id is a number im sure i need to first convert to a string then use sub string but it gives me an error says "id.toString()"  is not a function.

I also tried a for each but im not as comfortable with for each loops as for loops:

```
<% expressModelName.forEach(function(result) {%>
result.id.toString()
```

this give me a 'catch' error

Comment: In mongodb normally it's _id not Id, BTW can you also tell sample data for id, in which format it is in DB

Comment: well whether its id or _id doesn't really do anything for me still needing to convert it to a string and then use substring on it. these variables aren't my exact ones im using im just adding in variables for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more trial and error and a little more research, I found `String(result.id)` to work.